# Why byte array converted to string then convert back to byte array is not same?

Tags: java

First read excel as byte array, then convert this byte array to string,  then convert this string to byte array again.

```
        String fileLocation = "/tmp/a.xlsx";
        byte[] bytes1 = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileLocation));
        String str = new String(bytes1);
        byte[] bytes2 = str.getBytes();
        System.out.println(Arrays.equals(bytes1, bytes2)); // false
```

Why `bytes1` is not equals to `bytes2`?

Comment: Why are you converting an "xlsx" file to String? Technically, I think they're zip archives with a bunch of files in them. Definitely not a string though.

Comment: This is not a good idea. A `String` is not suitable for holding arbitrary binary data. If you need really need to do this, then you should use something like Base 64 encoding.

Comment: @matt because excel contains some invalid characters (`<ffff>`) and poi read it failed So I want to convert it to string then replace `<ffff>` as empty string

Comment: The invalid characters are going to look different when zipped. Plus a lot of zip file characters are going to be invalid and `str.getBytes()` will probably not be a valid xlsx file afterwards. I see you've also asked the other question too. You could try unzipping the file, locating the invalid characters anre replacing them. I don't think it is very practical.

Comment: String is logically a `char[]`, not a `byte[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are converting from bytes to a String

```
String str = new String(bytes1);
```

you are potentially losing non-char bytes.

As per the javadocs

*The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the default charset is unspecified.*